# Show that this characteristic function is positive definite for $\alpha \in (0,2]$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I have a symmetric characteristic function $\phi$ which, through a series of steps in a textbook I have, is shown to be equal to the following function:

$$\phi(t) = \exp(-c|t|^{\alpha}), \ \ c > 0$$

The author states that since every characteristic function is positive definite, this imposes the condition on $\phi$ that $0 < \alpha \leq 2$ however I fail to see how this is true. All I have is the definition of positive definiteness for $z_i \in \mathbb{C}$:

$$\sum_{h,k = 1}^n \phi (t_h - t_k)z_h\bar{z}_k \geq 0$$

at my disposal and I can't see how this depends on the value of $\alpha$ since $\phi$ is positive everywhere. Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: The condition is that each matrix whose $h,k$ entry is $\phi(t_h-t_k)$, is a positive definite matrix, not that the entries are positive.

Comment: Ok sure, but then this still means that the sum above should be greater than zero, right? How can that depend on $\alpha$?

Comment: Your sum has to be positive for *all* $z$ vectors. This is a pretty complicated condition that depends on all the matrix entries, which depends on $\phi$, which depends on $\alpha$.  One might ask, why do you think it *doesn't* depend on $\alpha$.